# Which preposition follows curiosity?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition follows the word curiosity?

Ex. To explore their curiosity (for/about/with) science?

Comment: Hits from Google Books... [curiosity **about** sex](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22curiosity+about+sex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):28,000; [curiosity for sex](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22curiosity+for+sex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):62; [curiosity with sex](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22curiosity+with+sex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):19; [curiosity over sex](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22curiosity+over+sex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):25.

Comment: To *explore curiosity* is a strange phrase in itself; would it mean to satisfy it or to examine it as an emotion?

Answer (score 3):

You'll usually hear that someone is curious *about* something or curious *to know* something.

From [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curious):

> The cat was naturally curious about its new surroundings.
>
> They were curious to find out who won the game.

Answer (score 1):

Most often:

> *curiosity about science.*

Alternatively:

> *curiosity of science*

[Ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curiosity%20of,curiosity%20about,%20curiosity%20for,%20curiosity%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1;,curiosity%20of;,c0;.t1;,curiosity%20about;,c0;.t1;,curiosity%20for;,c0;.t1;,curiosity%20with;,c0)
[image: Ngram]

Comment: -1 for that totally non-idiomatic "alternative".

Comment: @FumbleFingers grammatically correct however.

Comment: I'm never really sure what "grammatical" means in such contexts - but I'm inclined to think the preferred preposition here is effectively *arbitrary*, so I guess it could have been something different. We are where we are though, and with 898 hits in Google Books for [his curiosity about sex](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his+curiosity+about+sex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and *none at all* for [his curiosity of sex](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his+curiosity+of+sex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), it's a pretty definite preference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers updated with Ngram. I should also add *curiosity of* is used as part of an example sentence in the New Oxford American Dictionary.

Comment: To me a "curiosity of science" would be a five legged cat or something.

Comment: +1, for doing a Ngram of "curiosity * " (which shows the use of the, in general, default preposition "of").

Comment: @njboot: I don't think those uncontextualised NGram results tell us anything about *actual usage*. And when I Google **New Oxford American Dictionary "curiosity of"**, all I see is irrelevant contexts like *become a curiosity of the past* and *engage the curiosity of the reader*. The reason I chose to search for ***his** curiosity about/of **sex*** was precisely to reduce or eliminate such accidental collocations which do not reflect OP's usage.

Comment: +1, for doing a Ngram of "curiosity * "